# utilizar variável para chamar ngFor no Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Eu tenho uma variável que eu exibo na tela do meu app chamada {{data.referencia}}.

No código de exemplo:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let cardapiohotrod of cardapiohotrod | async">{{cardapiohotrod.nome}}</ion-item>
```

Onde está escrito cardapiohotrod eu gostaria de colocar a variável {{data.referencia}}

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema? Não entendi o erro. Se puder colocar mais partes do código ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Brother, o ngFor serve para dar loop. em arrays por exemplo, pois assim ele pegará as posições do array.
Mais se você quer mostrar o conteúdo caso haja valor na variável. você pode usar: *ngIf ou [hidden]...etc

Pelo que vejo essa variável é uma posição de array já. neste caso você não conseguiria dar o loop nela pois contém apenas um valor.